# Gmail Markup not working send via Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses, google-schemas

I'm using the Amazon SES service to deliver an email to my customer that includes event markup its not synced with the calendar. However, I do not send over Amazon SES in the sense that it will sync with the calendar. I'm using markup-approved mail-id.

I'm expecting like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uusbF.png)